# Laravel "public"-folder error 403 (forbidden) - using Uniform Server (Apache)

Tags: windows, .htaccess, apache2, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to create my first MVC project with the help of the framework **Laravel**, using the server platform **Uniform Server**. (Uniform Server uses **Apache**.)

The problem is, I cannot seem to get my routes to work. I suspect this is because upon trying to access http://localhost/project_name/public/, I receive the following error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /project_name/public/ on this server.
```

i.e. error 403.

After some research it seems that this is a .htaccess problem, or a problem with my server configuration. This is because, if I have understood things right, access is simply not being granted to the folder.

Sounds easy enough to fix, but none of the fixes I find seem to work, or do not apply to the server platform I use. I must be missing something.

Moreover, while browsing my folders in localhost, the public folder is not actually displayed, like the others. I "reach" it only by typing the path into the URL field. However the folder obviously exists there as I'm getting a 403 error and not 404. And of course it appears as it should in file explorer.

---

**This is my .htaccess file:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

**And for Uniform Server, this is the httpd.conf file:**

```
#############################################
### Uniform Server - Apache Configuration ###
#############################################

# Environment variable ${PHP_SELECT} has a value of php52,
# php53, php54, php55 or php56. It is used in the following
# five define statements to select a PHP version to
# load as a module.
Define ${PHP_SELECT}

<IfDefine php53>
   Include ${US_ROOTF}/core/apache2/conf/extra_us/php53.conf
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine php54>
   Include ${US_ROOTF}/core/apache2/conf/extra_us/php54.conf
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine php55>
   Include ${US_ROOTF}/core/apache2/conf/extra_us/php55.conf
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine php56>
   Include ${US_ROOTF}/core/apache2/conf/extra_us/php56.conf
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine php70>
   Include ${US_ROOTF}/core/apache2/conf/extra_us/php70.conf
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine php71>
   Include ${US_ROOTF}/core/apache2/conf/extra_us/php71.conf
</IfDefine>




#
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/> for detailed information.
# In particular, see 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directives.html>
# for a discussion of each configuration directive.
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "logs/access_log"
# with ServerRoot set to "/usr/local/apache2" will be interpreted by the
# server as "/usr/local/apache2/logs/access_log", whereas "/logs/access_log" 
# will be interpreted as '/logs/access_log'.
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
# ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to specify a local disk on the
# Mutex directive, if file-based mutexes are used.  If you wish to share the
# same ServerRoot for multiple httpd daemons, you will need to change at
# least PidFile.
#
AcceptFilter http none
EnableSendfile Off
EnableMMAP off 

ServerRoot "${US_ROOTF}/core/apache2"
PidFile ${US_ROOTF}/core/apache2/logs/httpd.pid


#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen ${AP_PORT}

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
#LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule auth_form_module modules/mod_auth_form.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
#LoadModule authnz_fcgi_module modules/mod_authnz_fcgi.so
#LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
#LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule buffer_module modules/mod_buffer.so
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
#LoadModule cache_socache_module modules/mod_cache_socache.so
#LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
#LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
#LoadModule data_module modules/mod_data.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
#LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
#LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
#LoadModule http2_module modules/mod_http2.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule heartbeat_module modules/mod_heartbeat.so
#LoadModule heartmonitor_module modules/mod_heartmonitor.so
#LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
#LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
#LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
#LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_debug_module modules/mod_log_debug.so
#LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
#LoadModule lua_module modules/mod_lua.so
#LoadModule macro_module modules/mod_macro.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
#LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
#LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
#LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
#LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
#LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
#LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
#LoadModule ratelimit_module modules/mod_ratelimit.so
#LoadModule reflector_module modules/mod_reflector.so
#LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
#LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
#LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
#LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
#LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
#LoadModule session_cookie_module modules/mod_session_cookie.so
#LoadModule session_crypto_module modules/mod_session_crypto.so
#LoadModule session_dbd_module modules/mod_session_dbd.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
#LoadModule slotmem_plain_module modules/mod_slotmem_plain.so
#LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
#LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
#LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
#LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
#LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
#LoadModule watchdog_module modules/mod_watchdog.so
#LoadModule xml2enc_module modules/mod_xml2enc.so
#LoadModule plua_module modules/mod_plua.so


#Added new module
<IfModule http2_module>
    ProtocolsHonorOrder On
    Protocols h2 http/1.1
</IfModule> 


<IfModule unixd_module>

User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin admin@${US_SERVERNAME}

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName www.example.com:80
ServerName ${US_SERVERNAME}

#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#

<Directory />
    #mine
    Options FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride all
    #Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "${US_ROOTF_WWW}"
<Directory "${US_ROOTF_WWW}">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes Includes

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.shtml index.html.var index.htm index.php3 index.php index.lua index.pl index.cgi
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog "logs/error.log"

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
    LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>


    #
    # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
    # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
    #
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>

    Alias /us_docs "${US_ROOTF}/docs/"

    #opt1>phpMyAdmin opt2>Adminer opt3>phpMyBaskupPro
    Alias /us_opt1 "${US_ROOTF}/home/us_opt1/"
    Alias /us_opt2 "${US_ROOTF}/home/us_opt2/"
    Alias /us_opt3 "${US_ROOTF}/home/us_opt3/"
    Alias /us_pac  "${US_ROOTF}/home/us_pac/"

    Alias /us_mongoadmin "${US_ROOTF}/home/us_mongoadmin/"
    Alias /us_pear "${US_ROOTF}/home/us_pear/"
    Alias /us_splash "${US_ROOTF}/home/us_splash/"
    Alias /us_extra "${US_ROOTF}/home/us_extra/"
    Alias /webalizer "${US_ROOTF}/webalizer/"
    Alias /us_test_access "${US_ROOTF}/home/us_access/www/"

    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "${US_ROOTF}/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
    #
    # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
    # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
    #
    #Scriptsock logs/cgisock
</IfModule>

<Directory "${US_ROOTF}/docs/">
  Options Indexes Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#== Default phpMyAdmin
<Directory "${US_ROOTF}/home/us_opt1/">
  Options Indexes Includes
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

#== Default Adminer
<Directory "${US_ROOTF}/home/us_opt2/">
  Options Indexes Includes
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

#== Default phpMyBackupPro
<Directory "${US_ROOTF}/home/us_opt3/">
  Options Indexes Includes
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

#== PAC - Location to serve proxy.pac
<Directory "${US_ROOTF}/home/us_pac/">
  Options Indexes Includes
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory "${US_ROOTF}/home/us_mongoadmin/">
  Options Indexes Includes
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "${US_ROOTF}/home/us_pear/">
  Options Indexes Includes
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "${US_ROOTF}/home/us_splash/">
  Options Indexes Includes
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "${US_ROOTF}/home/us_extra/">
  Options Indexes Includes
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "${US_ROOTF}/webalizer/">
  Options Indexes Includes
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "${US_ROOTF}/home/us_access/www/">
  Require all granted
</Directory>

#
# "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#

<Directory "${US_ROOTF}/cgi-bin/">
  AllowOverride All
  Options ExecCGI
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "${US_ROOTF}/home/admin/www/cgi-bin/">
  AllowOverride All
  Options ExecCGI
  Require all granted
</Directory>


<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz


    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml

    # PAC files e.g proxy.pac
    AddType application/x-ns-proxy-autoconfig .pac

    #used for configuring auto detect setting using DNS
    #AddType application/x-ns-proxy-autoconfig .dat 

</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

# Supplemental configuration
#
# The configuration files in the conf/extra/ directory can be 
# included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of 
# the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as 
# necessary.

# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

# Multi-language error messages
#Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

# Fancy directory listings
Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

# Language settings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf

# User home directories
#Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

# Real-time info on requests and configuration
Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf

##====== VIRTUAL HOST ===========
#To enable uncomment next line
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
#Include conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf

# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
#Include conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf

# Various default settings
Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf

<IfModule ssl_module>
# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
</IfModule>

# Deflate Module configuration
<IfModule deflate_module>
Include conf/extra/httpd-deflate.conf
</IfModule>

# FastCGI Module configuration
<IfModule fcgid_module>
Include conf/extra/httpd-fcgid.conf
</IfModule>

# Proxy Html Module configuration
<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/httpd-proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

# Uptime Module configuration
<IfModule uptime_module>
    Include conf/extra/httpd-uptime.conf
</IfModule>

# Uniform Server Lua config
<IfModule lua_module>
   Include conf/extra/us_lua.conf
</IfModule>

# Uniform Server pLua config
<IfModule plua_module>
   Include conf/extra/us_plua.conf
</IfModule>

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
#Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
   ThreadStackSize 8888888
</IfModule>
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

I checked my apache error log and found this:

> [Fri Dec 01 12:24:50.572746 2017] [rewrite:error] [pid 20384:tid 1844]
>   [client ::1:60851] AH00670: Options FollowSymLinks and
>   SymLinksIfOwnerMatch are both off, so the RewriteRule directive is
>   also forbidden due to its similar ability to circumvent directory
>   restrictions :
>   C:/Users/Admin/Uniform/UniServerZ/www/project_name/public/

Aha! So perhaps it is indeed my server configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the 403 error by editing httpd.config like so:

```
DocumentRoot "${US_ROOTF_WWW}"
<Directory "${US_ROOTF_WWW}">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes Includes

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted

        #ADDED THIS
        #Options FollowSymLinks
        Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch


</Directory>
```